# Username is not correct recognized

Tags: support, questions, edits, user-accounts

A long time ago (>1year) I have asked a question at stackoverflow.com. For a long time there were no answers, but recently there were two answers, which show the need to edit my question.
However this seems not to be possible. In fact my profile do not show, that I asked this question.
How can the correct association between the question and the username be restored?

Edit:
The question in [Control Fujitsu Softune debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90891/control-fujitsu-softune-debugger).
I am not aware that I ever used an other OpenID account, but it may be possible that the account was deleted. I used SO for some time without login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/

for rules on abandoned accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Flag the question for moderator attention and explain your problem, or add a link to your question here and wait.

Answer (score 0):

Your account in SO is only 12 days old. When you asked the question, did you have an account? If so, did it use the same OpenId?

After searching for your name, I found this question: [control-fujitsu-softune-debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90891/control-fujitsu-softune-debugger). There is no account associated. Either the account has been deleted, or you asked this question anonymously.

You could include a link to the question in this answer and maybe some moderator will link it to your account. Or flag the question, as John says.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer pointed in the right direction and finally led to the answer from Jeff which explains the situation.